# unable to remove footer for psql ressult in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, psql

I have a psql command where I am able to get result but i unable to remove footer 
my command

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh mptios@xx.xx.xxx.xxx  "PGPASSWORD=xxxxx psql -a -h 11.11.111.11 -d TGM_bb_les -U bi_it -t -c \"select count(1) from dwpub.td_bank \" "
```

my result for above command :-

```
select count(1) from dwpub.td_bank
    29
```

but I need output as

```
29
```

I have tried this command but still unable to get expected output

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh mptios@xx.xx.xxx.xxx  "PGPASSWORD=xxxxx psql -a -h 11.11.111.11 -d TGM_bb_les -U bi_it --pset\"footer=off\" -c \"select count(1) from dwpub.td_bank \" "
```

can anyone help me with this

Comment: Did you try with `\pset tuples_only on` witch will disable both header and footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use grep or egrep to match digits only.

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh mptios@xx.xx.xxx.xxx  "PGPASSWORD=xxxxx psql -a -h 11.11.111.11 -d TGM_bb_les -U bi_it --pset\"footer=off\" -c \"select count(1) from dwpub.td_bank \" " | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with command:

```
sshpass -p 'password' ssh mptios@xx.xx.xxx.xxx  "PGPASSWORD=xxxxx psql -a -h 11.11.111.11 -d TGM_bb_les -U bi_it -t -c \"select count(1) from dwpub.td_bank \" "|tail -1
```

This will show only the last line